# Conditional statement within article entry affecting all subsequent entries in ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

I am building a slideshow gallery that is populated via EE CMS. Each "slide" in the slideshow is basically a mini-slideshow itself, with up to three slides. To keep the mini-slideshow from showing empty slides I use conditional statements and that is where the problem arises. If there is no second or third slide on the first entry it hides them for all subsequent entries. I need the conditional to perform the check for each entry. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <!-- TITLE & METADATA -->
    <title>SparkleMasters :: Photographic Sequin Imagery</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <!-- CHROME AND VIEWPORT SETTINGS -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <!-- FAVICON, HUMANS.TXT, STYLES & SCRIPTS REQUESTS -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="author" type="text/plain" href="/humans.txt" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all" title="global" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/_js/bootstrap.js?css=;js=" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="skip_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#navigation">Skip to the navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content">Skip to the content</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page" class="clearfix">
        <aside>
            <header>
                <h1><a href="#/">SparkleMasters :: Photographic Sequin Imagery</a></h1>
            </header>

            <nav>
                <a name="navigation" id="navigation">Site Navigation</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="about" href="#/about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="gallery" href="#/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a class="buzz" href="#/buzz">Buzz</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="latest-news">
                <h3>Latest News</h3>

                <ul>
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="buzz" limit="2"}
                    <li><a href="#/buzz">
                        {title}
                    </a></li>
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section id="contact-us">
                <h3>Contact Us</h3>

                <p><a href="mailto:&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#064;&#115;&#112;&#097;&#114;&#107;&#108;&#101;&#109;&#097;&#115;&#116;&#101;&#114;&#115;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#064;&#115;&#112;&#097;&#114;&#107;&#108;&#101;&#109;&#097;&#115;&#116;&#101;&#114;&#115;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;</a></p>

                <p>818 434 1464</p>

                <p>1128 Linden Ave 3
                    <br>Glendale, CA 91201</p>

                <form id="ajax-join-mailinglist-form" action="javascript:;">
                    <h3>Join Mailing List</h3>
                    <fieldset>
                        <ol>
                            <li class="inline">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="text" id="email" name="email">
                            </li>
                            <li style="display:none;"><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" 
                                value="Mailing List signup from sparklemasters.com"></li>
                            <li class="right">
                                <input type="image" src="/_images/btn-join.png" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <div id="note"></div>
            </section>

            <section id="copyright">
                <p>&copy; 2012 SparkleMasters. All rights reserved.</p>
            </section>

        </aside>

        <div id="body">
            <section id="primary">
                <a name="content" id="content"></a>
                <article id="gallery-detail">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" orderby="gallery_snapshot_order" sort="asc"}
                        <li>
                            <article class="sub-gallery">

                                <div class="caption-title">
                                    <h2>{title}</h2>
                                    <p>{project_type-location}</p>
                                </div>                  

                                <ul class="sub-slides">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="img-next-click" href="javascript:;"><img src="{large_img_one}" width="886" height="604" alt="{title}"></a>
                                        <span class="caption-bar"></span>
                                        <div class="detail-copy">
                                            {paragraph_one}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    {if large_img_two}
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="img-next-click" href="javascript:;"><img src="{large_img_two}" width="886" height="604" alt="{title}"></a>
                                        <span class="caption-bar"></span>
                                        <div class="detail-copy">
                                            {paragraph_two}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    {/if}

                                    {if large_img_three}
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="img-next-click" href="javascript:;"><img src="{large_img_three}" width="886" height="604" alt="{title}"></a>
                                        <span class="caption-bar"></span>
                                        <div class="detail-copy">
                                            {paragraph_three}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    {/if}
                                </ul>
                            </article>
                        </li>
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </ul>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting large_img_two and large_img_three into a <p> or something to make sure they're coming through for each entry? Is there more to this page? Is this the only channel entries loop, or is it embedded into another?

Comment: both large_img_two and large_img_three output as the source for the images in the LIs encapsulated by the conditional statement. And they do output the path to the image. For the gallery detail page this is the only channel, it is not embedded into another. Would you like to see the full page source?

Comment: The full page source would be great, thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the JS you're using for the slideshow is emptying the image src attribute for the additional images, because the image tags are there in the generating HTML, but the `src` attribute is empty.

Comment: I've updated my question with the full source for the page.

Comment: What fieldtype are the image fields? File? Assets? Or just text inputs where you type out the file paths?

Comment: Can you show us what is actually output by EE?

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the page, what does the rendered output look like?  Would you be able to post that as well so we can see how EE in interpreting your template?

Have you tried using {if large_img_two != ""} to make the conditional explicitly an "if not empty kind of thing? Depending on the field type, sometimes a blank field still contains a value.  What type of field is large_img_two, large_img_three? Native EE file field? Assets field? Channel Images field?